# Splitting a string by a specific sort of HTML tag

Tags: java, regex

Currently, I am working with a Vaadin RichTextArea, which displays its output in HTML. However, since a lot of my output is in XML format, the tags are converted to entities. That is, `<someTag>` becomes `&ltsomeTag&gt`. Now, suppose I have the following string:

```
&ltsomeTag&gtVALUE&lt/someTag&gt
```

How would I split this String so that the resulting String array consists of only VALUE? I've tried the following:

```
&lt[^(&gt)]*&gt

&lt[.&&[^(&gt)]]*&gt
```

But both of these just give me the complete String... I've also tried escaping all of the ampersands except for the `&&` in the second case since I need that to be parsed as an AND. However, nothing changed. Where is my logic going wrong?

Comment: Why are you splitting instead of matching?

Comment: Because there might be multiple values surrounded in tags, and I want to get all of the values...

Comment: So iterate through the matches.

Comment: And why shouldn't I be allowed to split?

Comment: You're allowed to do whatever you like. It just seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Are there no semicolons in there?  For example `&lt;someTag&gt;` or something similar?

Comment: (And you may want to read up on lookaheads and lookbehinds in regular expressions - they probably help here).

Comment: `[^(&gt)]` does not do what you think. It's a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), means it only matches individual characters, i.e. not a `(`, `&`, `g`, `t`, or `)`. The easiest way to skip text until the next `&gt`, is a [lazy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) (aka [reluctant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#reluc)), like this: `&lt.*?&gt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the replace all method to take out the tags, but needed to make sure the regex uses the non-greedy one to match the first closing bracket `.*?`

```
    String input = "&ltsomeTag&gtVALUE&lt/someTag&gt";
    String output = input.replaceAll("&lt.*?&gt", "");      
    System.out.println(output);
```

Output is

```
VALUE
```

Comment: Hm, so if there's multiple occurrences, such as: &ltsomeTag&gtVALUE&lt/someTag&gt&ltsomeTag2&gtVALUE_2&lt/someTag2&gt, I could replaceAll with some sort of special character (such as a colon or vertical bar or whatever) and then split by that character in order to get an array.